# Zariski closures exercise.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-verification

Compute the Zariski clousures  $\overline{S} \subset \mathbb{A}^2(\mathbb{Q})$ of the following subsets:

(a) $S=\{(n^2,n^3):n \in \mathbb{N}\}\subset \mathbb{A}^2(\mathbb{Q})$;

(b) $S=\{(x,y): x^2+y^2<1\}\subset \mathbb{A}^2(\mathbb{Q})$;

(c) $S=\{(x,y): x+y \in \mathbb{Z}\}\subset \mathbb{A}^2(\mathbb{Q})$.

I've write (a) and I don't know if it's right. I don't know how to make b and c

(a) Let $P(X,Y)=X^3-Y^2 \in \mathbb{Q}[X,Y]$. $P$ is $0$ in every element of $S$, because $P(n^2,n^3)=(n^2)^3-(n^3)^2=0, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}.$ Fixed $x_0=n^2 \in \mathbb{N}$, $ P(x_0,Y)$ is $0$, at least, in $y_0=n^3$, so $Y-y_0|P(x_0,Y)$. Hence, the number of roots of $P(x,y)$ it's the same than $Card(\mathbb{N})$. $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field, so every polinomial with degree  $d$ has $d$ roots. So neccesarily $P(x,y)$ is $0$, so $\overline{S}=\{(a_1,a_2)\in  \mathbb{A}^2(\mathbb{Q}): f(a_1,a_2)=0, \forall f \in I(S) \}=\mathbb{Q}^2.$ $$ $$

Comment: Every polynomial with degree $d$ does not have $d$ roots. $\mathbb{Q}$ is not algebraically closed.

Comment: Also, the closure of $S$ in (a) cannot be all of $\mathbb{Q}^{2}$. The polynomial $P$ that you defined in your proof is $0$ on all of $S$. Hence, 
$$\overline{S} \subseteq V(f) = \{(q^{2}, q^{3}) : q \in \mathbb{Q}\} \subsetneq \mathbb{Q}^{2}.$$
I believe that this should be the closure but my intuition for $\mathbb{Q}$ algebraic geometry is weak. Similarly, I believe that the closure in (b) and (c) should be $\mathbb{Q}^{2}$,but I could be mistaken.
I'm not fully able to understand what you've done in your proof so I can't give any help there.

Comment: Dear @Siddarth: your intuition is correct. Anyway it is a very poor idea to give algebraic geometry exercises over $\mathbb Q$ to a beginner.